# Редирект всех странциц содержащих фрагмент

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Помогите сделать правильный редирект. Сейчас есть страница

```
/filtr.hml
```

У нее могут быть get параметры в конце, нужно это все (все запросы) 301 редиректом перевести на

```
/shop/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопался, нашел готовое решение.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /catalog/
RewriteRule .+ /page.php [L,R=301]
```